# i was also told to use: int get_input(char message[]) in my code but i don't know how to use it

Tags: c, xcode, computer-science

i was given an assignment to write a code prompting the user to input an even number (and to continue prompting if the number was not even) and after the even number is input prompt the user to input an odd number. I was also told to use: int get_input(char message[]) in my code but i don't know where and how to use it. this is the code below.

````
            ```
            #include<stdio.h>
            int main(int argc,char**argv)
 {
          int num_odd;
          int check_even;


           printf("Enter an even number: ");
           scanf("%d",&check_even);

  do{

            if (check_even%2==0)
    {
             printf("Ok thanks! Now enter an odd number\n");
              scanf ("%d",&num_odd);
    {
           break;
    }
    }

        else
    {
        printf("That is not even enter an even number. Enter an even number:\n");
        scanf("%d",&check_even);
    } }while ('check_even%2!=0' && 'check_even%2==0');

    do
    {
     if (num_odd%2!=0)
      {
   printf("**Thanks bye!**");
   {
       break;
   }
   }
       else
   {
       printf("That is not an odd number. Enter an odd number.\n");
       scanf("%d",&num_odd);
   }

    }while ('num_odd%2==0' && 'num_odd%2!=0');


     }
     ```
````

Comment: Drop the single quote marks..

Comment: Think about `check_even%2!=0 && check_even%2==0`.  How is that ever true?

Comment: I removed the single quotes and the code stopped working correctly

Comment: david, what about `check_even%2!=0 && check_even%2==0`.  What do you think that does?

Comment: loops the code as long as check_even is odd and even. not really sure.

Comment: david `check_even%2!=0 && check_even%2==0` is certainly never true as `check_even%2` cannot be non-zero and zero.  It is one or the other.

Comment: I understood what you said and removed the single quotes and used OR and got the same result. Thanks

Comment: `(check_even%2!=0) || (check_even%2==0)` is always true.  That tests (if an integer is odd or if an integer is even).  All integers are either odd or even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i was also told to use: int get_input(char message[]) in my code but i don't know how to use it

The name, parameter and return type of this function as well as the [problem](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/problem-2-write-program-submit-file-called-evenoddc-q58085660) description indicate that you are supposed to use it for prompting and inputting the number, i. e. rather than

```
           printf("Enter an even number: ");
           scanf("%d",&check_even);
```

you shall use

```
           check_even = get_input("Enter an even number: ");
```

Comment: i tried but it gave an error message: error: called object 'get_input' is not a function or function pointer|

Comment: I see now from [Chegg](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/problem-2-write-program-submit-file-called-evenoddc-q58085660) that you are expected to create that function.

Comment: I don't understand